# Perl script working but too slow

Tags: performance, perl, loops

My script is designed to read scripts of the following form:

```
fixedStep chrom=chr1 start=3 step=1
0.006
0.010
fixedStep chrom=chr1 start=9 step=1
0.002
0.004
0.005
fixedStep chrom=chr1 start=14 step=1
0.010
0.020
0.028
0.666
0.777
fixedStep chrom=chr1 start=22 step=1
0.005
0.009
0.012
0.555
```

The script works on short "practice files" of this sort.  Its output looks like:

```
.....
.....
.....
0.006
0.010
.....
.....
.....
.....
0.002
0.004
0.005
.....
.....
0.010
0.020
0.028
0.666
0.777
.....
.....
.....
0.005
0.009
0.012
0.555
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
```

So, what the script is doing is listing in a single column two important things derived from the original file.  The first kind of important thing is all those four digit decimal numbers.  The second kind of important thing is the variable number of instances of `.....`.  Those represent "missing" four digit numbers.  The number of `.....` that occur before and after any continuous stretch of decimal numbers is calculated from the information contained in lines beginning with `fixedStep...`.

The ultimate point of the script is to convert large versions of the practice file show here into a large version of the output. But as I said, my solution is slow. Any ideas to improve?  I do have another script already written to read the output, and that script is expecting output of the particular format I just described.

Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

unless(@ARGV) {
    exit;
}

my $chrpc = shift;
open( PHAST, "<$chrpc" );
```

This just opens up the file.  Next, I slurp the original file.  I know that is slow, but I the path I saw toward the solution started with this.  I suspect this is the most significant thing slowing stuff down. Later on the script gets a little convoluted, I admit, and that could be "cleaned up", hopefully with an impact on performance and not just for esthetics.

```
my @wholething = ();
while ( <PHAST> ) {
    my $line = $_;
    chomp $line;
    push( @wholething, $line );
}
```

Next, I start to reorganize the data. I also add in some things, like commas or the word "end", in anticipation of using those to help split/join things together at subsequent steps.  First, I make container `@chunked` and push into it the first line of the file and a comma.

```
my @chunked = ();

push ( @chunked, $wholething[ 0 ], ",");
```

Then a loop through `@wholething`, and push into `@chunked` the next lines of the file containing the decimal numbers and also the next line containing `fixesStep`, a comma, "end", and then the same line again, followed by a comma.

```
for ( my $i = 1; $i < scalar @wholething ; $i++ ) {
       if ( $wholething[ $i ]=~m/fixedStep/ ){
       chomp $wholething[ $i ];
       push ( @chunked, $wholething[ $i ],",", "end\n", $wholething[ $i ], ","  ); 
  }    

  else {
      chomp $wholething[ $i ];
      push ( @chunked, $wholething[ $i ], "," );
  }
}
```

In the end, what we have is a bunch of "chunked" bits of file, where each of the continuous runs of decimal numbers are bracketed by adjacent `fixedStep` containing lines, except for the last chunk, whose run of decimal numbers is bracketed by the last `fixedStep` line at the front.  With the original file chunked like this, I could use the information in the flanking lines to decide how many `.....` to add to represent the "missing" information. For the last chunck, I manually enter in a value to help make those decisions. But now, I join `@chunked` into a giant string, and then split it at all the occurrences of "end".

```
my $bigstring = join ( "", @chunked );
my @chunked_array = split ( "end" , $bigstring );
#print "@chunked_array\n\n";
```

Now with the file reorganized, I begin to make the new file. I make a container `@pc_array` and define `$last` to be some value.  Recall above that in the chunked form, each run of decimal numbers was bracketed by adjacent `fixedStep` lines, except for the last chunk.  The value given by `$last` is used to help bracket the end of the last chunk. Here, that number is huge. If it matters, this value is the final position of a chromosomal sequence. All the lines of the output correspond to base positions in chromosomes (so the files are huge). For practice files, is set `$last` to a much smaller number.

```
my @pc_array = ();
my $count = 1;
my $last = 61342429;  ## enter here value of final position for given chr.
```

A `for loop` to cycle through each chunk and figuring out how many `.....` to add in between chunks. For the first time through the loop, I calculate how many `.....` to add to the array before the first decimal number.  The last time through the loop I use `$last` to help figure out how many `....` to add at the end.  For the rest, I push into the array the decimal numbers, followed by the appropriate number of `.....`.  I also generate in the output some sanity checks to make sure things are working out correctly.  I will remove those at the end in order to generate the final form of the output.

```
for ( my $i = 0; $i < scalar @chunked_array  ; $i++ ) { ## $i = chunk number

      my @lines = split ( "," , $chunked_array[ $i ]);

      my $distance = scalar @lines - 2 ; ## gives number of pc score lines 
      ## notice extra comma in @entries. 


      my ( $position_1, $position_2 ) = ($chunked_array[ $i ] =~ /start\=(\d+)/g); 
      my $post_fill = $position_2 - ( $position_1 + $distance ) ;

      if ( $i == 0 ){ ## when first chunk

           push ( @pc_array, 0, 0, ".....\n" );

           for ( my $j = 0; $j < $position_1 - 1 ; $j++ ){

                 ## fill in 'pre-missing' scores with .'s

             push ( @pc_array, $i, $count, ".....\n" ); 
             $count++;
       } 

        ## fill in pc scores
        for( my $j = 0; $j < $distance; $j++ ){

             push( @pc_array, $i, $count, "$lines[ 1 + $j ]\n" ); 

             $count++;
         }

         ## fill in post-missing pc scores with .'s
         for ( my $j = 0; $j < $post_fill  ; $j++ ){
               push ( @pc_array, $i, $count, ".....\n" ); 
               $count++;
         } 

  } 


  elsif ( $chunked_array[ $i ] eq $chunked_array[ -1 ] ) {
          ## when last chunk

          ## fill in pc scores
          for( my $j = 0; $j < $distance; $j++ ){

               push( @pc_array, $i, $count, "$lines[ 1 + $j ]\n" ); 

               $count++;
          }

          my $final_post_fill = $last - ( $position_1 + $distance ); 

          ## fill is post-missing pc scores with .'s
          for ( my $j = 0; $j < $final_post_fill + 1  ; $j++ ){
               push ( @pc_array, $i, $count, ".....\n" ); 
               $count++;
         }



  }



  else { ## when first or else not the last chunk

        ## fill is pc scores
        for ( my $j = 0; $j < $distance; $j++ ){

             push( @pc_array, $i, $count, "$lines[ 1 + $j ]\n" ); 

             $count++;
         }

         ## fill is post-missing pc scores with .'s
         for ( my $j = 0; $j < $post_fill  ; $j++ ){
               push ( @pc_array, $i, $count, ".....\n" ); 
               $count++;
         } 

   }

}
```

I look at the array.  The first line of the output is off by a space. There's an extra space added in at the beginning.

```
print @pc_array;
```

I do the following to remove the space but also mainly to remove the sanity checks in the output, in order to arrive at the final form of the output I require.

```
my @pc_col =();

for ( my $i = 2; $i < @pc_array; $i=$i+3 ) {
      chomp $pc_array[ $i ];
      print "$pc_array[ $i ]\n";
      push ( @pc_col, $pc_array[ $i ]."\n");
}

print @pc_col;
open( OUT, ">chr19_pc_col.txt");
print OUT @pc_col;
```

Like I said, the script works but I could use some pointers to optimize it.

Comment: Your code is extremely awkward to read split up like that. It is usually best to put as *few* comments as possible into your code. Please can you describe how the `fixedStep` lines translate into dotted lines in the output? I don't see the *"two instances of `start=` followed by a number"* that you mention.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. edited that out.

Comment: Okay, but please explain how to determine the number of dotted lines to add.

Comment: In the `fixedStep` lines, there is the term `start=` some number. That number refers to the position number of the succeeding decimal number.  So I need to add 3 `....` lines before the first decimal number. After the first run of decimal numbers is in the array, I need to add 4 lines of `....` because the next `start=` value is 9.  This is a "zero indexed" sort of file, where the first line is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got yourself very tangled up.

As far as I can tell this program seems to do what you need. I assume the `step` attribute is always one, or at least can be ignored, and that the `chrom` field is similarly irrelevant.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $out, '>', 'chr19_pc_col.txt' or die $!;

my $last = 30;

my $line = 0;
while (<>) {
  if (/^fixedStep.*start=(\d+)/) {
    my $start = $1;
    while ($line < $start) {
      print $out ".....\n";
      ++$line;
    }
  }
  else {
    print $out $_;
    ++$line;
  }
}

print $out ".....\n" for $line .. $last;

close $out or die $!;
```

**output**

```
.....
.....
.....
0.006
0.010
.....
.....
.....
.....
0.002
0.004
0.005
.....
.....
0.010
0.020
0.028
0.666
0.777
.....
.....
.....
0.005
0.009
0.012
0.555
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
```

Comment: that's close. it just lacks the final set of `.....`  Not sure what the `chrom` field is you refer to, or `step`.  There is `$count` which i set to 1 but then use to help count off the lines in initial output, just as a sanity check. I remove that in the end to make the final output.  I'll try your idea.

Comment: oh...yes i understand what you mean now.  yes, the step attribute is always 1 (i hope).   by chrom field, does that refer to something about what to do at the very end of the output?

Comment: There's no way of knowing how many extra lines to add at the end because the `fixedStep` records say only where the next number should appear.

Comment: @ES55: The `fixedStep` records have a `chrom`, a `start` and a `step` attribute.

Comment: yes, that's right.  In my script, there's a line where I add in the value of the very last position (i called it `$last`). i can modify your answer to do that.   But what is `chrom` field?  I don't understand that part.

Comment: oh. i see. yes, in the original file.  I thought you were referring to something in the script. ok.  thanks.

Comment: @ES55: I've added to my solution to allow for a `$last` value to be specified. I've set it to 30 so that the output is now identical to your own.

Comment: much sleeker than mine. i need to learn more commands and tricks. thanks.  i'll test it out on a big file and see how it compares for speed.

Answer (score -2):

Slurping does tend to cause performance issues with large files.

I won't do the whole thing for you, but it looks like a pattern similar to this might help get you started:

```
#buffer, holds a few lines of the input file
my @chunk_lines = ();

#read line-by-line until end of file
while (!eof $fh) {
    my $line = readline $fh;
    if ($line =~ /^fixedStep/) {      #if this line is the start of a new chunk...
        process_chunk(@chunk_lines);  #process data
        @chunk_lines = ();            #clear buffer
    }

    #either way, push this line onto the buffer
    push @chunk_lines, $line;
}

#process any remaining buffer
process_chunk(@chunk_lines);
```

If you can process each chunk individually, that's good. Anything where you `push` a bunch of values into an array, and then `split` it down for processing? That's a spot you might be able to optimize.

If passing an empty `@chunk_lines` to `process_chunk` is bad, you could avoid it simply:

```
process_chunk(@chunk_lines) if @chunk_lines;
```